# Passing audio between scenes cocos2d

Tags: iphone, audio, cocos2d-iphone

Just started working with cocos2d, so far ive set up different scenes eg main menu, settings and about. Ive added some background music to the main menu scene like so:

```
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"TileMap.caf"];
```

The music passes through to the other scenes, but when i go back to the main menu scene  the sound restarts itself.

I have only been doing this about 3 weeks now, so be easy on me :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should check if background music is currently playing with `[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] isBackgroundMusicPlaying]`, and if its currently playing just do nothing instead of calling `playBackgroundMusic` again in your main menu scene

Comment: Ok i see what you mean, ive done something like this. Am i going in the right direction with is?`SimpleAudioEngine *sae = [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine];
  if (sae !=nil) {
   [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"TileMap.caf"];
  } 
 else {
  sae = [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine];
 }`

Comment: no, you should do this to assure that it only plays once: `if(![[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]isBackgroundMusicPlaying]){[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"TileMap.caf"];} ` and you don't have to check if its nil because the sharedEngine always return a singleton of SimpleAudioEngine, so it will never be nil at your eyes

Comment: Thank you, i know there silly questions but it really helps :)

Comment: dont worry :) i'm glad to have helped you, if you found my answer correct plz check it as answered

Comment: in addition I want to on/off all the sounds including touch sounds at the same time. how can I do that? I have tried setMute:NO. But on transition to another scene how can I check if the music is on?